# cannot display text onchange select option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have 1 set of `<select><option>` which is if I select 1 option by it value, it will display some text in `<div>`.

This is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#selectcom').change(function() {
    opt = $(this).val();
    if (opt == "comp_id") {
      $('#new_text').html('Varchar');
      $('#size_row').html('20');
    } else if (opt == "comp_name") {
      $('#new_text').html('Varchar');
      $('#size_row').html('20');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>
    <select class="selectField" onChange="" id="selectcom">
     <option value="">-- Select Field --</option>
     <option value="comp_id">comp_id</option>
     <option value="comp_name">comp_name</option>
     </select>
  </td>
  <td id="data_row">
    <div id="new_text"></div>
  </td>
  <td id="size_row">
    <div id="size_row"></div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

The problem is I cannot display any output either `varchar` text or `20` text  with this code. Anyone please help me. Thank you..

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: your snippet looks working. are you sure you include jquery?

Comment: Works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/gp89s4uq/ Are you loading jquery? Show us your full code

Comment: Your requirement is not clear, and as @hungrykoala commented, your code seems to be running fine.

Comment: Your code is running ok. Are you sure you include jquery in the head of html? From what you see us i think you dont have jquery included.

Comment: your snippet is working fine

Comment: thank you all. I make silly mistake. I misplace the referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No enough information; yet try to make sure you included jQuery reference in :

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

In case you did that , as I can see from jsfiddle. I suspect the css is showing the output in white...try to show some css code.

Answer (score 1):

It works. I would suspect that you haven't referenced jQuery before your script block/file. Check the developer's console. Does it display something like:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Solution: Make sure your jQuery file is loaded before your script block/file.

Like:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="your-jsfile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Not like:

```
<script src="your-jsfile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#selectcom').change(function() {
    opt = $(this).val();
    if (opt == "comp_id") {
      $('#new_text').html('Varchar');
      $('#size_row').html('20');
    } else if (opt == "comp_name") {
      $('#new_text').html('Varchar');
      $('#size_row').html('20');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>
    <select class="selectField" onChange="" id="selectcom">
     <option value="">-- Select Field --</option>
     <option value="comp_id">comp_id</option>
     <option value="comp_name">comp_name</option>
     </select>
  </td>
  <td id="data_row">
    <div id="new_text"></div>
  </td>
  <td id="size_row">
    <div id="size_row"></div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Also, I recommend using a [`switch`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) statement. I don't know about performance, but in my opinion, it improves readability.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#selectcom').change(function() {
    opt = $(this).val();
    switch (opt) {
      case "comp_id":
        $('#new_text').html('Varchar');
        $('#size_row').html('20');
        break;
      case "comp_name":
        $('#new_text').html('Varchar');
        $('#size_row').html('20');
        break;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>
    <select class="selectField" onChange="" id="selectcom">
     <option value="">-- Select Field --</option>
     <option value="comp_id">comp_id</option>
     <option value="comp_name">comp_name</option>
     </select>
  </td>
  <td id="data_row">
    <div id="new_text"></div>
  </td>
  <td id="size_row">
    <div id="size_row"></div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

First check console if you are getting some error due to other script also remove onChange="" if you are using direct jquery on change function, or use below approach.

```
<tr>
    <td>
    <select class="selectField" onChange="changeMyValue(this.value)" id="selectcom">
    <option value="">-- Select Field --</option>
    <option value="comp_id">comp_id</option>
    <option value="comp_name">comp_name</option>
    </select>
    </td>
        <td id="data_row"><div id="new_text"></div></td>
        <td id="size_row"><div id="size_row"></div></td>
        </tr>   


function changeMyValue(opt) {
    if (opt=="comp_id") 
    {
        $('#new_text').html('Varchar');
        $('#size_row').html('20');
    }
    else if (opt == "comp_name") 
    {
        $('#new_text').html('Varchar');
        $('#size_row').html('20');
    }
}
```